# Java Remote method invocation

Tags: java, rmi

If i call this server method with the client from different location iam getting following error.If i run the client from same location where the server is there I am getting output.

Please give some soltuions to call my rmi server with rmi client from different location.

```
Error
Exception in thread "main" java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.transform.xsl.XslFoTransformer_Stub (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.Naming.lookup(Naming.java:101)
    at com.transform.xsl.RmiClient.main(RmiClient.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.transform.xsl.XslFoTransformer_Stub (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:394)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:184)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:637)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:264)
    at sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveClass(MarshalInputStream.java:222)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1610)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1515)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1769)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    ... 3 more
```

Code ======

```
import java.io.File;
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface XslFoTransformerInterface extends Remote {
    public byte[] doTransform(File stylesheet, File datafile) throws Throwable,RemoteException;

}

public class XslFoTransformer extends UnicastRemoteObject  implements XslFoTransformerInterface {

    protected XslFoTransformer() throws RemoteException {
        super();

    }

    public byte[] doTransform(File stylesheet, File datafile) throws Exception {

        String fileName = datafile.getName();
        int pos = fileName.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (pos > 0) {
            fileName = fileName.substring(0, pos);

        }
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        File file = new File(fileName + ".xsl-fo");
        try {
            // File stylesheet = new
            // File("C:\\Users\\Q811213\\Documents\\XSLT\\files\\ECGSearchResultsPDF_changed1.xsl");
            // File datafile = new
            // File("C:\\Users\\Q811213\\Documents\\XSLT\\files\\NEWDATA.xml");
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = builder.parse(datafile);
            TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            StreamSource stylesource = new StreamSource(stylesheet);
            Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(stylesource);
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            StreamResult result=new StreamResult(bos);
            transformer.transform(source, result);
             byte [] array=bos.toByteArray();


        return array;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }}}


--Rmi server class


public class RmiServer {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{  
        try{  


        XslFoTransformerInterface stub=new XslFoTransformer();  
        Naming.rebind("rmi://localhost:1099/Xsl-Fo_Transform",stub);  
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw e;

        }  
        }  

}


--Rmi client created in different location



public class RmiClient {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Throwable {
        try {
            XslFoTransformerInterface stub = (XslFoTransformerInterface) Naming
                    .lookup("rmi://localhost:1099/Xsl-Fo_Transform");
            System.out.println("stub is ready" + stub);
            File f1 = new File(
                    "C:\\Users\\s811213\\osbwstest\\XSL-FO_Transformer\\files\\ECGSearchResultsPDF_changed1.xsl");
            File f2 = new File(`enter code here`
                    "C:\\Users\\s811213\\osbwstest\\XSL-FO_Transformer\\files\\NEWDATA.xml");
            try {
                byte[] f = stub.doTransform(f1, f2);
                }cartch(){}

}}
```

If i call this server method with the client from different location iam getting following error.If i run the client from same location where the server is there i am getting output.
    Please give some soltuions to call my rmi server with rmi client from different location.

Answer (score 0):

You need to deploy the stub class named in the exception to the client.

Answer (score -1):

In RMI client

XslFoTransformerInterface stub = (XslFoTransformerInterface) Naming
                    .lookup("rmi://localhost:1099/Xsl-Fo_Transform");

you need to change localhost to server ip

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is: 
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.transform.xsl.XslFoTransformer_Stub (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)

Comment: An incorrect IP address does not cause a ClassNotFoundExceptuon.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if you running your program in different locations (no the server machine) with the updated version of your code for ip which you hard coded for localhost.

If this is not the problem, you must be sure that you placed the XslFoTransformerInterface class in your client codes **in the same package as it is in server codes**.

Also in the future if you have some Serializable POJO classes as the arguments or the return types of you remote methods, same rule is applied for them. Always put them in the same package as they reside is the server codes.

Good Luck.

Comment: i have added the XslFoTransformerInterface in client location but still it is giving same error

Comment: for example if the package for XslFoTransformerInterface is: com.java.rmi in the server project, in the client project you should have the com.hava.rmi package and place your XslFoTransformerInterface interface in there. Did you do it?

Comment: Which java version do you use?

Comment: There's no way of changing the package of the stub. The Java version doesn't have anything to do with it either.

Comment: Dear @EJP, I think you've voted down my answer incorrectly, because both of the situations I've explained in the above can produce such exception. First of all if you don't use RMI in the production and use it without a public codebase, you should temporarily and manually put the Remote interface and the Serializable POJOs in the client project codes. This situation can happen if the interfaces or POJOs are put in a different package in the client project. So certainly this produce a ClassNotFoundException.

Comment: @EJP: Also if the java version is below 1.5, programmer should manually create stub and skeleton using rmic command, I'm sure you know that better than me. So java version can matter in this case.

Comment: As there is no way to change the package of a stub, it isn't a package-change problem. As the stub already exists and was transmitted from the server, and not found at the client, it isn't a stub non-generation problem.  As voting here is secret, you don't know who downvoted this question.